# Replacing a decimal within a field name in an ADF expression

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to look up the date field in a .csv file using the lookup fuction and then the setvariable function in an ADF pipeline. However, I debug the pipeline I receive an error due to the decimal being within the field

[global.businessDate field]
[image][Set Variable Error Message][image][Set Variable expression][image]

I tried entering the field in the exact format, as well as underscore and single and double quotations.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because dot in the field name as you stated in the OP. To solve this, you can give the below expression in the set variable activity.

```
@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow['global.businessDate']
```

By this way, you can read the value from the column which has special character(dot).

[image]